# Usage of Multiple Queries to get data from different tables

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am new to DATABASE and MYSQL so don't have much experience or knowledge with handling queries

I have two tables `students` and `login` in MYSQL database, *they both have 1:1 relation, Primary key of student is a foreign key in login*.

So login table has both `Student_ID`(FK) and `Password`

I want to run a query in a JAVA program that will check the `id` and `password` entered by the user in `login` table and then return the matching `student` object data from student table

So far this is what I am doing for login the user put in `username` and `password`

```
public Student validate_Student(String s, String t)
    {
        int w = Integer.parseInt(s);
        int q = 0;

    String iD = "";

    Student obj = new Student();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE Student_ID = " + w + " and Password= " + t;

    try
    {
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            iD = rs.getString("Student_ID"); //matching record

        }

        int i = Integer.parseInt(iD); // check the previously searched matching record in student table 
        String query1 = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE ID = " + i;

        ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs1.next()) {
            obj.setID(rs1.getString("ID"));
            obj.setName(rs1.getString("NAME"));
            obj.setAddress(rs1.getString("ADDRESS"));
            obj.setPhone(rs1.getString("PHONE_NO"));
            obj.setEmail(rs1.getString("EMAIL"));
            obj.setDOB(rs1.getString("DOB"));
            obj.setDegree(rs1.getString("DEGREE"));

        }

    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Problem in Query");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return obj;
}
```

I am not quite sure how to use UNIONS in the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query will return student details whose login credentials match.

```
SELECT s.* FROM student s JOIN login l on s.id = l.Student_ID WHERE l.Student_ID = " + w + " and l.Password= '" + t + "'";
```

- Join student table to login table using one to one relation `s.id = l.Student_ID` where `s` is the alias for student table and `l` for login table.
- to return only student details use `s.*` in select statement.

Comment: I am getting this error

Problem in Query
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'abc123' in 'where clause'

In Login table, I have Student_ID (Column Name) as 121 and Password  (Column Name) as abc123 and in Student Table, I have ID (Column Name) 121

Comment: Missed single quotes around password column. Have updated the query in the post. Enclose password in quotes. e.g. `l.Password= '" + t + "'";` since its a string value.

Comment: Did this fix your issue?